# Defining and using a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I'm trying to define and use a variable in a batch file. It looks like it should be simple:

```dos
@echo off

set location = "bob"
echo We're working with "%location%"
```

The output I get is the following:

```
We're working with ""
```

What's going on here? Why is my variable not being echo'd?

Answer (score 737, accepted):

The space before the `=` is interpreted as part of the name, and the space after it (as well as the quotation marks) are interpreted as part of the value.  So the variable you’ve created can be referenced with `%location %`.  If that’s not what you want, remove the extra space(s) in the definition.

Comment: So this is what MS came with

Comment: @Falaque As opposed to `alias x = y` in *nix land?

Comment: @Falaque so what do you think bash will do when running `x = y`?

Comment: Consider also using 'SetLocal' & 'EndLocal' (- where relevant).  ;)

Answer (score 350):

The spaces are significant. You created a variable named `'location '`
with a value of
`' "bob"'`. *Note - enclosing single quotes were added to show location of space.*

If you want quotes in your value, then your code should look like

```
set location="bob"
```

If you don't want quotes, then your code should look like

```
set location=bob
```

Or better yet

```
set "location=bob"
```

The last syntax prevents inadvertent trailing spaces from getting in the value, and also protects against special characters like `&` `|` etc.

Comment: Are there any downsides for the last syntax?

Comment: @Wolf - No, there is no downside. However, there is a limit to when it is most effective. As long as the value does not contain quotes, then almost any characters can appear in the value without worrying about escaping. The exceptions are `%`, and possibly `!` if delayed expansion is enabled. But if the value does contain quotes, then you must worry about when to escape poison characters like `|`, `&`, etc.

Comment: this seems to be same as setting the environment-variable in windows. Is this the  only way of using local-variables in batch scripts?

Comment: @Wolf, you only have to ensure that the [command extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) are enabled, but this is the default configuration anyway...

Answer (score 14):

input `location.bat`

```
@echo off
cls

set /p "location"="bob"
echo We're working with %location%
pause
```

output

```
We're working with bob
```

(mistakes u done : `space` and `" "`)

Comment: `set /p` prompts the user and stores the answer in the specified variable. e.g., `set /p name="What is your name? " & echo Hello, %name%.`

Comment: -1, The syntax `set /p "varname"="text"` is wrong, it creates a variable named `location"` (with a trailing quote!). It should be `set /p location="bob"`. But even then, it doesn't match the question anymore

Answer (score 6):

Consider also using [`SETX`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - it will set variable on user or machine (available for all users) level though the variable will be usable with the next opening of the cmd.exe ,so often it can be used together with `SET` :

```
::setting variable for the current user
if not defined My_Var (
  set "My_Var=My_Value"
  setx My_Var My_Value
)

::setting machine defined variable
if not defined Global_Var (
  set "Global_Var=Global_Value"
  SetX Global_Var Global_Value /m
)
```

You can also edit directly the registry values:

> User Variables: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment

> System Variables: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Which will allow to avoid some restrictions of SET and SETX like the variables containing `=` in their names.

#### 3rd party edit

> SETX.exe
> Set environment variables permanently,
>
> SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU):

Option `/m`

```
 /m
       Set the variable in the system environment HKLM.
       (The default is the local environment HKCU)
```

Another example

```
::setting variable for the current user
if not defined JAVAJDK (
  set "JAVAJDK=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin"
  setx JAVAJDK "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin"
)
```

In a command.exe you can use the variable like this `cd %JAVAJDK%`.