# Issue with a variable in my batch script

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

I want my script to:

- Accept a variable
- Create a path using that variable as input
- Display the path
- Display the contents of the directory

What is wrong with the following code? The `ECHO` statement just prints `Your directory is set to`; the `DIR` statement works as expected.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET custompath = "C:\Users\%1"
ECHO  Your directory is set to %custompath%
DIR %custompath%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the space around the `=`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET custompath="C:\Users\%1"
ECHO  Your directory is set to %custompath%
DIR %custompath%
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552812/declaring-and-using-variable-in-batch-file).

Comment: `echo DIR %custompath%` --> `DIR`

`echo DIR %custompath %` --> `DIR  "C:\Users\"`

Comment: Works fine, as long as the path exists ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do it this way:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P "custompath=Enter a custom windows path: "
ECHO Showing contents of directory ^"%custompath%^"
DIR /b "%custompath%"
pause
```