# Batch file if statement not working with cmd

Tags: c, batch-file, if-statement

i have looked for an answer and have not found one.

```
@echo off
:a
cls
set /p %a% =
if %a% == 1 goto b
goto c
:b
echo.
echo worked
pause
:C
echo.
echo dident work
pause
```

i set a = 1 and is said that the goto command was unexpected at this time. any help would be great

Changed

ok it has been change and a new problem occurs. now when a = 1 it always goes to c not b

```
@echo off
:a
cls
set /p a = 
if "%a%" == "1" goto b
goto c
:b
echo.
echo worked
pause
:C
echo.
echo wierd
pause
```

Comment: For an explanation as to why your code is failing, look at the answers to this question: [Declaring and using a variable in DOS/Windows batch file (.BAT)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812/1012053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off  
echo.  
set /p a=  
echo.  
if %a%==1 goto b  
if not %a%==1 goto c  
:b  
echo worked  
echo.  
pause  
exit  
:c  
echo dident work  
echo.  
pause  
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
set /p %a% =
```

to

```
set /p a=
```

and

```
if %a% == 1 goto b
```

to

```
if "%a%" EQU "1" goto b
```

Comment: just did still says " goto unexpected at this time"

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off&cls
set /p a=Enter a number : 
if "%a%" EQU "1" goto:b
echo dident work
exit/b

:b
echo Result = 1
```