# SVN checkout bat file error

Tags: batch-file, svn, syntax-error, svn-checkout

I have created a batch file as below:

```
set SVNExe = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"
set SVNURL = "https://server.local/svn/MyProject/"
set CheckOutLocation = "E:\Projects\MyProject"
%SVNExe% checkout %SVNURL% %checkOutLocation%
@pause
```

When I run this file, I get the following error:

> Try svn help checkout for more information.
>
> Not enough arguments provided.

I don't know which arguments are missing as the definition of svn checkout says:

```
svn checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
```

And per this my syntax is correct.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't put spaces around the equal sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812/1698557) when using `set`.  This will work:

```
set SVNExe="C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" 
set SVNURL="https://server.local/svn/MyProject/" 
set CheckOutLocation="E:\Projects\MyProject" 
%SVNExe% checkout %SVNURL% %checkOutLocation%
```

Also if you need to debug this, just put `echo` before the command you're trying to execute:

```
echo %SVNExe% checkout %SVNURL% %checkOutLocation%
```

With your original file, it outputs:

```
 checkout
```

With the fixed version (no spaces), it outputs:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"  checkout "https://server.local/svn/MyProject/"  "E:\Projects\MyProject"
```