# REG command after SET is "unknown" in DOS/Windows batch file (.BAT)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, batch-processing

In my batch file I started to use variables and suddenly the following commands do not work anymore.

Here is the part of my code with the problem

```
SET "path=MyPath"
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\ETC\ETC" /f /v "MyRegNameA" /t REG_SZ /d "%path%\ETC\"
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\ETC\ETC" /f /v "MyRegNameB" /t REG_SZ /d "%path%"
PAUSE
START "" "%path%\MyProgram.exe"
```

This code works without the `SET...` and of course with `MyPath` instead of `%path%`. Error Message is:

```
The command "REG" is either spelled wrong or couldn't be found
```

I previously found how to use Variables here: [stackEx.SetVariables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552812/declaring-and-using-a-variable-in-dos-windows-batch-file-bat)
To my knowledge I am doing it exactly as supposed, and I couldn't find specific help so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`path` is a logical name, but it's not a good name to use as it is assigned by Windows.

`path` is a semicolon-separated list of the directories that Windows uses to find programs. When you change it, Windows can no longer find `reg.exe` since `reg.exe` is not in `mypath`.

Simply choose another name - don't use `path`. If you enter `set` at the prompt, you will see a list of many of the variables that are established by Windows. Simple rule - don't use any of them for user-variables.