# Batch File - Having trouble escaping some special characters in a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to set a varaible to the output of a command using a for loop, as another question on here discussed, but I'm getting stuck on some special characters that are screwing with the result. Here's what I've written:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('netstat -b ^| find ""coresrvr.exe"" ^| find /c /v """"') do set output=%%i
```

That doesn't seem to be working though. It gives me "File not found - CORESRVR.EXE and then has the output = 0. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: `set output = %%i` will set a variable named `output`<space> to the value <space>`%%i`; write `set "output=%%i"` (no spaces!) instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I got it, the quote escaping was unnecessary. Here's the correct code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('netstat -b ^| find "coresrvr.exe" ^| find /c /v ""') do set output=%%i
```

Comment: NO. You defined a variable named `'output '` with a space at the end, which I am pretty sure is not what you want. See [Declaring and using a variable in DOS/Windows batch file (.BAT)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812/1012053) for more info.

Comment: Oh shoot, I copied it over wrong, sorry. See I wrote all this remotely just for convenience sake, and I couldn't copy and paste it, so I just wrote it from scratch. It's correct in the actual code. Thanks though!