# Batch (Windows) set variable to first argument doesn't work

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

I have a batchscript mybatch in which I try to store the first user argument in a variable called FILE

```
set FILE = %1 
if defined FILE (
  echo defined
  echo do something with %1
  ) else (
   echo not defined %1 
  )
```

If I execute my batch via mybatch test1 I get always not defined test1. Why is variable FILE not defined?

Answer (score 5):

You have unwanted spaces in your variable assignment, so you have defined a variable with a space in the name that always has a value beginning with a space. Your IF statement is checking if a variable without a space exists.

See [Declaring and using a variable in Windows batch file (.BAT)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812/1012053)

I recommend your first line should be:

```
set "FILE=%~1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
@echo off
set "FILE=%~1" 
if Exist "%FILE%" (
    echo.
    echo "%FILE%" Exist
    echo do something with "%FILE%"
  ) else (
   echo "%FILE%" is not defined 
)
Pause
```