# Time maximums in Windows shell and Why?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made a *simple countdown* in [Windows Batch Scripting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting):

```vbs
@ECHO OFF
MODE con: cols=13 lines=2
COLOR 4f
TITLE Countdown Timer
SET /p m=? Minutes:
SET /a s = 60 * m
FOR /l %%a in (%s%,-1,1) do (
  ECHO %%a/%s%
  PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL 2>&1
  CLS
)
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 EXIT
CSCRIPT alert.vbs
EXIT
```

and I noticed the following things:

1. the maximum *seconds* that I can use, is exactly the [eighth Mersenne prime:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%2C147%2C483%2C647) `2147483647` *([2147483647 seconds to years at DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=2147483647+seconds+to+years&atb=v145-7__&ia=answer))*, but
2. if I use the multiplier `60` to start the *countdown* with *minutes*, the maximum accepted integer is `1037950429.99999999`.

   - *[1037950429.99999999 minutes to years](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=1037950429.99999999+minutes+to+years&atb=v145-7__&ia=answer)* equals `1973.43904479` which refers to the day of [June 10, 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/June_1973#June_10,_1973_(Sunday)) 9:00 AM, but from my research nothing special happened in that day.

Doing my research to understand **why(?)**, led me to ask this question.

[image: windows command calculations]

Comment: It has nothing to do with limits in time measurement. It has to do with the precision of integers, which are signed 32-bit in command or batch files, IIRC.

Comment: don't use spaces around `=` in batch like `SET /a s = 60 * m`. [Don't use ping to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/995714). And 2147483647 is simply 2³¹-1 which is the largest 32-bit integer (which cmd uses). Besides `set /a` doesn't support floating-point operations, thus `set /a 1037950429,99999999*60` is exactly the same as `set /a 99999999*60`. If you want to use 64-bit int or double then you must use other scripting languages like powershell or VBS

Comment: Also, arbitrarily deciding that a certain number of minutes starts at any base point in time is a mistake. You've correlated that (incorrectly) to June 10, 1973 at 9:00, but that isn't accurate. It's just a certain number of minutes - there's no beginning reference point for those minutes other than the one you've decided to assign. IOW, if I start a timer now and let it run for 10 minutes, the beginning reference point of that timer is not in 1970, but the time when I started the timer. Your `1973` means 1973 years period, not 1973 years from a specific starting point. 2019+1973 is valid.

Comment: To get the maximum positive number in 32-bits precision, enter `set /A 0x7FFFFFFF` at the command prompt. For the minimum negative number, enter `set /A 0x80000000`

Comment: Thank you for your amazing comments, now i have all of my answers! Paying with the date was just fun ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282) because Windows already has a command for counting down: [`timeout`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html). There's no reason to re-implement that unless you want more control over it

---

Regarding the observed behavior, cmd.exe (as well as its [`set /a` internal command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1)) uses only **32-bit integers**, therefore the maximum value it can represent is 2147483647 = 2<sup>32</sup> - 1

> The numbers must all be within the range of 32 bit signed integer numbers (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647) to handle larger numbers use PowerShell or VBScript.
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

It's an *extremely common* constant in computers, since we almost all use 32-bit int. The correlation to Mersenne prime is just purely accidental due to the choice of bit width

And from the above link you can see *comma is a **separator operator*** just like in C-like languages, **not a radix point**. In fact I've never seen a programming language that uses comma as radix point like in written languages.

> `,`   Commas separate expressions    `set /a "_num=2,_result=_num*5"`

If you run `set /?` you'll see the comma in the precedence table

```
The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
is a numerical expression that is evaluated.  The expression evaluator
is pretty simple and supports the following operations, in decreasing
order of precedence:

()                  - grouping
! ~ -               - unary operators
* / %               - arithmetic operators
+ -                 - arithmetic operators
<< >>               - logical shift
&                   - bitwise and
^                   - bitwise exclusive or
|                   - bitwise or
= *= /= %= += -=    - assignment
  &= ^= |= <<= >>=
,                   - expression separator
```

That means `1037950429,999999999*60` is simply 2 expressions, one calculates `1037950429` and discard, and the other calculates `999999999*60`, which overflows 32-bit int and returns a negative value as you see

```
C:\Users\>set /a 1037950429,999999999*60
-129542204
C:\Users\>set /a 999999999*60
-129542204
C:\Users\>set /a 1037950429,99999999*60
1705032644
C:\Users\>set /a 99999999*60
1705032644
C:\Users\>set /a 1037950429.999999999*60
Missing operator.
```

Even if you want to do operations with floating-point values such as `1037950429.999999999` then you're out of luck since that exceeds the precision of the biggest *binary* floating-point type in VBS and PowerShell which is [IEEE-754 double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) and can only be accurate to ~15 decimal digits. PowerShell does have a [128-bit *decimal* floating-point type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7#numeric-type-accelerators) (inherited from [.NET's decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netcore-3.1)) that helps a bit in that case though:

```
PS C:\Users> 1037950429.999999999d * 60
62277025799.999999940
```

---

Also note that `set a = b` in batch means assigning a string  `b` with a space before into a variable named `%a %`. Spaces are significant in `set` command, thus don't use spaces around the `=` operator. See

- [Batch (Windows) set variable to first argument doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36839995/995714)
- [Batch File Set Variable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19448522/995714)