# Using for loop bat file windows for multiple command calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, shell, batch-file

I want to export all data from sql server table to a csv, I know I can get the desired result by:

```
sqlcmd -S . -d database -E -s, -W -Q "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME" > file.csv
```

I have many tables, so I want to create a .bat file that do the work for me, I have this:

```
set "list = A B C D"


for %%x in (%list%) do (
    sqlcmd -S . -d database -E -s, -W -Q "SELECT * FROM %%x" > %%x.csv

)
```

But I am getting errors I don't know (I am not an expert in bat files). Why this does not work? How can I do what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring and using a variable in DOS/Windows batch file (.BAT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552812/declaring-and-using-a-variable-in-dos-windows-batch-file-bat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spacing is important when using `set` (unless you're doing math with the `/A` switch).  As written, the variable you're setting isn't `%list%`.  It's `%list %`.  Change your `set` command as follows:

```
set "list=A B C D"
```