# Unrecognized command error when using SET in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```bat
set month = 10
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (input.txt) do (
    if /I not %%i == %month% (
        echo %%i >> "output.txt"
    )
)
```

I got `'10' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how can I compare "10"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring and using a variable in Windows batch file (.BAT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552812/declaring-and-using-a-variable-in-windows-batch-file-bat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces in `set` command is significant. `set month = 10` will create a variable named `"month "` (with space after) with a value `" 10"` (with a space before). Just try `echo %month %` and see

Because the variable `%month%` is not available, `if /I not %%i == %month% (` will be expanded as `if /I not %%i == (`, which results in an invalid syntax. Another lesson: always surround `if` parameters with `""` so if the variable expands to an empty string it'll still work

Besides, to avoid a trailing space is included on each line, you should move the redirection to before the command

The final result will be like this

```bat
set month=10
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (input.txt) do (
    if /I not "%%i" == "%month%" (
        >>"output.txt" echo %%i
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks. will accept this answer later. Sorry for being a newbie.