# Invalid Index Error

Tags: python, batch-file

I am having trouble getting the second argument I am sending to a Python script?
I am unsure of how to fix it and changing the second argument to a value or putting a %1 in front of the arguments has not worked. Here is my current code does anyone know what the error might be?

Batch File Code:

```
`@echo off`
set /p UserInputPath=Enter the location of your development unit?
set /p ScriptPath =Enter script path?
python part2.py %UserInputPath% %ScriptPath%
```

Python File Code:

```
unitPath = sys.argv[1]
scriptLocation = sys.argv[2]
```

> scriptLocation = sys.argv[2]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I've never done any Batch programming, but the empty space between `ScriptPath` and `=` could cause the issue..
Otherwise, try in your python script, above `scriptLocation = sys.argv[2]`
to `print(sys.argv)` it should be a list of the arguments passed. If you don't get your supplied arguments, the problem is within the batch code

Comment: debug this by doing `print sys.argv` (for python2) or `print(sys.argv)` for python3 so you see the content of `sys.argv`

Comment: @Sativa: Bang on! the posted code sets a variable named `scriptpath[space]`, not `scriptpath`, hence the Python routine sees only one argument, not two. I'd suggest you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: The extra space was this issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, If you read the help file for the `SET` command you would see the syntax plain as day. `SET [variable=[string]]`. No spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is within your Batch File, as you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552812/declaring-and-using-a-variable-in-windows-batch-file-bat) answer, using spaces within the declaration of Variablenames, will result in the space being a part of it.