# Variables not set in the batch file

Tags: batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
If "%computername%"=="USER-PC" (
    set abc = ZZZ.bat
    echo %abc%
    pause
)
```

Here abc always shows blank. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Refer also to these posts: [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10558316), and [Declaring and using a variable in Windows batch file (.BAT)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812)

Answer (score 2):

You're *halfway* there, inasmuch as you've enabled delayed expansion. However, delayed expansion uses the `!` characters rather than `%`, so what you need is:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%computername%"=="USER-PC" (
    set abc=ZZZ.bat
    echo !abc!
    pause
)
```

Note also that:

```
set abc = ZZZ.bat
```

does *not* create an `abc` variable, it creates an `abcspace` one and sets it to `spaceZZZ.bat`, as per:

```
C:\Users\pax> set abc = 1
C:\Users\pax> echo .%abc%.
.%abc%.
C:\Users\pax> echo .%abc %.
. 1.
C:\Users\pax> set xyz=1
C:\Users\pax> echo .%xyz%.
.1.
```

You'll see I've removed the spaces around the `=` character to fix this.