# save and display user input values in .bat not working

Tags: batch-file

I am unable to figure out why the value is not stored in a variable in  Windows 10.
I search on the internet didn't get any reason why this not working.

```
@echo off
:start
REM check if there are more then one argumnets
if not "%2" == "" (
echo Too many parameters entered 
) ELSE (
REM check if argument one is empty
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%1"=="" (
echo "Enter your Name"
SET /P filename=
echo Your Name  is "%filename %" 
) 
if "%filename%"=="" (
echo "empty"
) else (
 echo "dat"
)
)
```

When I run this:

```
Enter your Name
asd
Your Name  is
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do SETLOCAL and ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679907/how-do-setlocal-and-enabledelayedexpansion-work). In addition the issue first mentioned in the comments is covered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812). As a side note, please don't expect our members to visit a web site to download a file and open it to read a small piece of code, you could have very quickly copied and pasted into your question. I have now edited your question to include the content of that file, please delete previous your comment above.

Comment: `"%filename %"` has to be `"%filename%"` (in fact, `"!filename!"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may also help you out:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If "%~1"=="" (
    Echo No parameter was passed
    GoTo EndIt
) Else (
    If Not "%~2" == "" (
        Echo Too many parameters entered 
        GoTo EndIt
    ) Else (
        Echo "Enter your Name"
        Set /P "filename="
        If "!filename!"=="" (
            Echo "empty"
        ) Else (
            Echo Your Name  is "!filename!"
            Echo "dat"
        )
    )
)
:EndIt
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```