# cmd command in ShellExecuteW

Tags: cmd, shellexecute, mql5, shellexecuteex

I want to delete a file using cmd comment. I run the code in MQL5 language from my EA. Here's the code that I used

```
string PathReportBacktest=sTerminalTesterDataPath+"\\MQL5\\Files\\Reports\\"+StrategyCategory+"\\"+StrategyName+"\\"+ FileName +" Report.xml";

ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "cmd", "/C del "+PathReportBacktest, "", 0)
```

I tried to use the show window option and I found that the cmd opens up and closed without doing anything.

Comment: Print the returned value to the console output when you run the ShellExecuteW command and refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew#return-value) to figure out what went wrong

Comment: done it before, it return 42 and according to documentation it runs successfully

Comment: If it ran successful then something is up with the file path. I don't think you can just concatenate string using + in cmd.  Refer this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552926/17985195) and try to build your PathReportBacktest string based on that

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still the data is exist

Comment: I tried using another file with extension txt and it works, tried to delete an excel file with extension .xlsx and it failed. So far only txt file that really deleted

Comment: Any reason, you cannot (want not) use [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew) directly?

Comment: It's not in the "Files" sandbox. I use 2 MT5 one for trading and the other for optimization. I need to delete file from the optimization MT5 from the trading MT5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things that I do to fix the problem,

- I found the problem which is the space within the file, if the file name is text.txt (doesn't have space) it works with the above but if the file name is text 1.txt, it will fail to delete the file.
- instead of using this code `ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "cmd", "/C del "+PathReportBacktest, "", 0)`

  I change it into `ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "cmd", "/C del [fileName]", "[file location]", 0)`

  e.g. `ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "cmd", "/C del text*1.txt", "D:\\folder1\\", 0)`